# how to truncate the primary key table if we have foreign key constraint for a column in another table?

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

Hi i am using sql server 2008 r2,
i have a genuine problem. 
i have a Table A and Table B, 
where i have a column IID in table A as a primary key constraint.
and the same column i.e. IID in table B as a foreign key constraint.
i have a situation where i wanted to truncate the table A. while running query Truncate table A it give me following error.

```
Msg 4712, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 
Cannot truncate table 'A' because it is being referenced by
a FOREIGN KEY constraint.
```

my problem i cant do any DML & DDL operation on table B.
how can i truncate table A ?
Thanks! in advanced.

Comment: Why woud you want to destroy the integrity of your db by truncating a table that has related records?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only way to allow a truncate is to drop the foreign key constraint(s) against table A. It doesn't matter if the constraint is disabled or if both tables are empty, SQL Server still will not allow it. So if you have the definition of the foreign key handy, you could do:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.TableB DROP CONSTRAINT FK_whatever;

TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.TableA;

ALTER TABLE dbo.TableB ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Whatever
  FOREIGN KEY ...;
```

Otherwise as @Damien says the solution to your "genuine problem" is to use `DELETE` instead of `TRUNCATE`. If you also were using `TRUNCATE` to reset the `IDENTITY` column, you can perform a `DELETE` and then a [`DBCC CHECKIDENT('dbo.TableA', RESEED, 1);`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176057.aspx)...

Answer (score 1):

If you can't do anything against Table B, then you're going to have to let SQL Server validate that its not removing rows which are referenced by Table B.

So, it's nice, slow, logged `DELETE FROM A`.

Comment: when i run the delete query it gives another error 

Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_PKIID". The conflict occurred in database "DBName", table "B", column 'IID'.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: Then there are rows in Table A that are being referenced by Table B. You're not allowed to remove those rows from Table A.

Comment: @VikrantMore you can't create a situation where rows in TableB reference rows in TableA that no longer exist. Perhaps you should better explain your actual goal. Why do you need to remove all the rows from TableA, but not from TableB?